# Is there a logic for deciding when to employ furigana?

Tags: orthography, furigana

I'm vaguely aware that the usage of *furigana* is based on the intended target audience. The younger or less likely literate the target audience the more *furigana* are employed. But is there a system to decide which words receive *furigana* and which don't? In intermediate novels I find it not unusual to find *furigana* on words that were printed without just a few pages earlier. Is this done because somebody decided that that word/reading is less likely to be known in that context, or is it pretty *"tekitō"*?

Comment: This is an intriguing question, but to me it seems closer to the subject of typesetting rather than language...

Comment: I know in my Japanese Bible, any lesser-known words/常用外/less-known-readings of words usually show the furigana on the first occurrence of the word per page.  Obviously the content of the Bible affords the use of pretty niche words/readings (i.e., lots of spiritual words) that will probably rarely/never be encountered elsewhere, so this is quite necessary.  For example, if the word 御霊 (みたま - Spirit of God) is one page 1 five times, and on page 2 three times, the furigana would appear on each page, but only on the first occurrence in that page.

Comment: @Derek: I share that feeling.

Comment: @derek: on second thought, this question would indeed be better suited for meta. But personally I think we should let it fly, on account of being a really nice question (if bordering on the off-scope) and the low volume of questions on the site at the moment.

Comment: I don't think this is a meta question at all. It's an important question about the usage of written Japanese. It should be the author and editor who make decisions about furigana, not the person operating the typesetting machine.

Comment: @hippietrail: This does cover written Japanese, but it only applies to those who need to know when to use furigana, i.e. those in the publishing industry. Knowing such furigana rules isn't necessary for the rest (read: vast majority) of those who want to write Japanese. Furthermore, properly answering this question would require knowledge of the Japanese publishing industry that is sufficiently broad and detailed enough to summarize current furigana trends. Otherwise we'll only get answers like, "I'm not sure, but this is what I've seen…"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't answer on the particular case of a word that would receive furigana *after* not receiving it earlier (the opposite, however, is naturally quite common): assuming the words are rigorously identical and identically read both times, this sounds more like an oversight than anything.

As for the general rules of adding furigana, they are pretty straightforward, depending on what kanji level can be expected from the reader.

One should probably separate:

- Readings targeting children and young adults (about anybody at High School age or under) have very fluid rules, as far as I can tell. *Overall*, they will try and follow the regular Japanese school curriculum, which is very specific about which kanji must be mastered by when. But since their target demographic itself might not be all that exact, they will probably err on the side of caution and annotate all **non-kyouiku kanji**.
- Regular readings: newspapers, novels, manga for adults (adult-*age*, not adult-*themed*) etc. will generally put furigana only for highly irregular readings and kanji that are **outside of the jouyou set**. I believe adding furigana to non-jouyou kanji is even a requirement by law for newspapers (but I cannot find a source for this just now). Of course, the socio-professional status of the intended audience will probably play a role in how generous with extraneous furigana they are  (e.g. cheap weekly magazines etc.), but I noticed such materials just tend to skip the kanji and go straight to kana when needed...

It must be said that the strictness in kanji requirement (compensated by the use of furigana) has dramatically decreased over the past 30-40 years: to convince yourself, just compare a copy of any 70s-era manga (e.g. Tezuka Osamu's *Black Jack*) with modern day mangas targeting the same demographic ("shounen" - young adult): the latter have furigana all over (anything beyond Jr High School level, essentially), while the former barely bothers putting furigana on even the most obscure proper noun kanji (let alone anywhere else).

**Edit:** there's been much debate in the answer below, regarding the existence of clearly-defined official guidelines (as opposed to obscure in-house rules). *At least for newspapers*, I stand my ground and reiterate: **Jouyou kanji** is the **officially agreed** base set of kanji to be used in Japanese publications, with some modifications clearly defined and agreed upon by the association of Japanese newspaper editors (source: [Wikipedia Jp](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E8%A1%A8)). One could argue that there is yet another small decision-making step from "kanji that people aren't expected to know" to "kanji that need to be furiganised", but frankly, I'm not going there.

Comment: -1 for the original answer being compleley unsupported with evidence. And also for the edit, because the question isn't about Joyo kanji. It's about the use of furigana. There is no debate that there is such a thing as an official Joyo list. But that is not what the question is asking. The question is clear: is there a system fo the use of Furigana. Respectfully, this answer only provides what the answerer thinks, it should not be taken to be representative of any agreed system in wide use.

Comment: @Dave: as I *do* mention in my edit, I really can't see how the connection between "sets of kanji that readers are expected to know" and "kanji that get furigana" could be any clearer... Furigana are a direct consequence of a kanji being outside of the recommended set for a specific readership (for instance Jouyou+mods for newspapers). As I have now pointed out multiple times (and *sourced* above) the *official* Association of Japanese Newspapers has clearly-defined guidelines for kanji use. If you can't see the direct connection between those and furigana use, I don't know what to say.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:

No.

Longer answer:

The thing that makes this a difficult question to answer with authority is that no one can provide evidence of something not existing. I can't prove a negative, so if someone can find any evidence of a system (with universal application, not just someone's in-house policies), then please do so.

Otherwise, until then, I am just about 100% sure that there is absolutely no system at all. It's entirely done, as you suggest in your question, based on the creator's (including all production levels of authors, editors, publishers, etc...) assessment of whether or not the reader can read the kanji.

Further, not only is there no system or agreed standards for when furigana should be employed, there is equally no system for when words that have kanji are written entirely in hiragana.

I am currently reading the adventures of Tintin in Japanese, and they make all sorts of seemingly random (to my non-native language level) choices about which words have furigana, which words are offered in hiragana, which words are never given furigana, and which words are given furigana once but not again. The people who translated it went case by case for each sentence assessing the reader's ability to read what was offered.

And that's pretty much how it's always done. The only "system" you might find would be within some publisher or company and applied to all their own materials, but that would be just as arbitrarily decided as any other publisher's choices.

Comment: That's somewhat true, but I'd say there is a standard - it's just not strictly adhered to. You'll find words that are statistically more likely to appear with furigana. It doesn't mean they always do, or that sometimes, in a single publication, you wouldn't find a less likely word furiganized while more likely word would remain without any furigana. But there is a system. It's just not strictly followed.

Comment: That said, I would be very surprised if the large Japanese publishers aren't giving their editors a thick guidelines booklet with very strict rules, which is followed religiously. In fact, thinking about it, given the relative simplicity of this task given good rules and the amount of text Japanese publishers handle regularly, I would be surprised if first pass furiganizing isn't done by computers these days.

Comment: @Dave, re. "there is absolutely no system at all": as I pointed in my answer above, this is not entirely true. While novels and comics *might* have arbitrary/in-house rules, I am pretty certain at least newspapers have to conform to strict rules (if not laws) regarding out-of-jouyou kanji use (and addition of furigana).

Comment: Guys, while I respect that you have as much reason to believe there *might* be a standard as much as I am pretty convinced there definitely is no standard, it's all just a bunch of talk until you provide an actual example.
I think the best you might do is some in-house thing, which I think is not quite in the spirit of the question. One company's internal rules doesn't represent much more than the whims of whoever wrote them. I think the question is trying to find a more generally applicable guide. Either way, though, I stand by what I said until there's something real to talk about.

Comment: @Dave: I reiterate. While I agree that without sources, it isn't very productive to throw hypotheses around on house style and private guidelines. **There are** clear, universal, and possibly legally-backed guidelines for newspapers and magazines. It would take somebody much more versed in Japanese law than me to find an acceptable reference, but Jp Wikipedia on 常用漢字 or [this page](http://www.pressnet.or.jp/news/headline/101130_916.html) sound like good places to start.

Comment: The article you link to is a 7 year old article about changes to jouyou kanji. Jouyou kanji and furigana are different issues. The jouyou kanji list is only a (ignored to the point of being irrelevant) guideline about what kanji should be considered common. Most Japanese don't even know what it is.
Look... I can see this is going to be one of those round and round debates, so I'm bowing out until someone provides an actual example of this supposed guideline for furigana. Burden of proof is on the positive. Anything else is just noise.

Comment: @Dave: Frankly, I don't really know where to start with the argument on "jouyou is only [ignored to the point of being irrelevant]". Jp Wikipedia (can't link because SE doesn't like UTF8 URLs) entry contains enough citations to official documents and government guidelines to say otherwise. "Most Japanese don't know what it is" is an incredibly poor argument in the current context. But indeed, this debate does not seem likely to go anywhere, so let's just leave it there for now.

Comment: @Dave: and btw, [新聞漢字表](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E8%A1%A8) linked from the Wikipedia page I mentioned says: "新聞漢字表は、新聞紙上で使用する漢字を定めた漢字表。新聞協会用語懇談会が示す。[...]新聞漢字表は、常用漢字表をベースに、字体または音訓の増減を施している". After that, if I still can't convince you that officially agreed upon (and clearly defined) guidelines for newspapers exist (based, guess what, **on the jouyou kanji set**), I give up.

Comment: @Dave: Whoah, I never said that Joyo Kanji isn't official. There are all sorts of guidelines and rules about the use of Joyo kanji. My point was at the end of the day, they are only guidelines, and if a Japanese person wants to step outside of them, they can and often do. Newspapers are chock full of non-joyo kanji. In any case, the question as stated above is about the application and use of Furigana. Furigana has no rules. Period. Or, show me some rules for furigana. Not for Joyo kanji, but furigana. Talking about joyo rules in it's place is just a deflection to try and blur the issue.

Comment: @Dave: I won't bother re-quoting all that has been said above. it's there for you or anybody else to see. I don't know what's not clear to you about "新聞協会用語懇談会". Marking a kanji as out-of-bound means it either doesn't get used or gets furigana. There's nothing mysterious or arbitrary about it. Sure, you "can" step out and won't get arrested by the Furigana police, these are still official guidelines. You claim "Newspapers are chock full of non-joyo kanji": please back up this claim.